# Structural equality affected by location of case class definition after deserialisation

Tags: scala, equals, json4s

Why is structural equality comparison affected, after deserialisation to case class instance,  by the location of case class definition being inside or outside another class. For example, the assertion in the following snippet

```
package example

import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods.parse

class Foo {
  case class Person(name: String)
  def bar = {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    val expected = Person(name = "picard")
    val actual = parse("""{"name": "picard"}""").extract[Person]
    assert(expected == actual, s"$expected == $actual")
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  (new Foo).bar
}
```

fails with

```
`java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Person(picard) == Person(picard)`
```

whilst it passes if we move `Person` definition outside `class Foo` like so

```
case class Person(name: String)
class Foo {
  def bar = {
    ...
    assert(expected == actual, s"$expected == $actual")
  }
}
```

Note, in both cases, deserialisation seems to be successful, for example,

```
assert(expected.name == actual.name)
```

is satisfied irrespective of `case class Person` definition location.

Perhaps it is somehow affected by the implicit `Manifest` passed in to [`extract`](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/83871251d2249128b3f4f501ffaa0634f94c2abf/core/src/main/scala/org/json4s/ExtractableJsonAstNode.scala#L20)?

Comment: And if you make `Foo` an object with inner `Person` you'll have `Exception in thread "main" org.json4s.package$MappingException: unknown error` `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: I am unable to replicate that. `object Foo {
  case class Person(name: String) ...` does not seem to throw exception for me.

Comment: I made them inner `object App {
  object  Foo {
    case class Person(name: String) ...`

Comment: Scala 2.12.8 + json4s-native 3.6.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug.

https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/564
"Deserialized inner case classes cannot be compared with case classes initialized in code"

Answer (score 2):

Looks like inner classes can't be meaningfully checked for equality since every instance holds a reference to the outer object. And these references are a part of equality check:

```
  class Outer {
    case class Inner(s: String)
  }

  val outer = new Outer()
  val a = outer.Inner("x")
  val b = outer.Inner("x")
  println(a==b) //true
  val c = new Outer().Inner("x")
  println(a==c) //false
```

Comment: The question is why `expected`, `actual` are like `a`, `c` and not like `a`, `b`.

Comment: Very strange: I tried to add `equals`/`hashCode` to `Outer` but still does't work. But if I do it in Java it works. So Java compares outer classes by `equals` and Scala by reference.

Comment: Not so strange. `outer.Inner` and `outer1.Inner` are different **types** (`equals`, `hashCode` are irrelevant). If `a` and `c` have different types then auto-generated `equals` gives `false` for them. Java doesn't have path-dependent types. Java type `Outer.Inner` is like Scala type `Outer#Inner`.