# Json4s Jackson read write case class not equal

Tags: json, scala, jackson, json4s

How can this be that a previously serialised and then deserialised case class is not equal:

```
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.{write, read}
implicit val formats: DefaultFormats = DefaultFormats

case class MyCaseTestClass(two: String, num: Int)
read[MyCaseTestClass](write(MyCaseTestClass("bla", 123))) shouldBe MyCaseTestClass("bla", 123)
```

And running this I get:

```
MyCaseTestClass(bla,123) was not equal to MyCaseTestClass(bla,123)
ScalaTestFailureLocation: ...
Expected :MyCaseTestClass(bla,123)
Actual   :MyCaseTestClass(bla,123)
```

Comment: Consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55890176/structural-equality-affected-by-location-of-case-class-definition-after-deserial This known behaviour is not due to ScalaTest.

Comment: Thx for the hint, I couldn't find this other entry unfortunately.

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, after trying around a while I found that defining a case class inside your unit test class that is enriched with FlatSpec with Matchers this causes the issue somehow.

If defining the class outside, e.g. in a separate file / object, this doesn't happen.